# Clone prototype function keeping scope

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have somewhat of an odd use case, but here it goes (below is an example, but the methods are named somewhat differently);

There's a prototype function name `bootstrap` on an object I'm using, which calls a function `create`. I want to modify it (without changing the prototype) in order to call `createCustom`. To do this, I'm `toString()`ing the prototype function, doing a String replace on the `create`->`createCustom`, then `eval`ing it back to a Function.

The problem is that the `bootstrap` function has several references to `this` inside it, and it appears that my cloned function no longer has the same scoping (sort of expected).

Any ideas if I can bind a certain context to get it back to what it should be in the cloned method? Nothing I have tried so far has worked, unfortunately.

I realise the method of getting what I want above is messy, but my hands are tied. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note: `this` and "scope" have basically nothing to do with one another. Scope relates to what variables are accessible to a function. `this` is fundamentally a function argument. (Except for ES6 "arrow" functions, which get `this` from the *context* -- not scope -- in which they were created.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your `eval`'d function, you can call it with any `this` value you want via [`Function#call`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4) or [`Function#apply`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.3):

```
// Call f with `this` referring to `obj`, arguments 1, 2, and 3
f.call(obj, 1, 2, 3);

// Same thing, note how the arguments are passed as an array
f.apply(obj, [1, 2, 3]);
```

**Live Example:**

```js
function Foo(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Foo.prototype.bootstrap = function() {
  create(this.name);
};
var obj = new Foo("The object");

// Not that I recommend doing this!
var f = eval("(" + obj.bootstrap.toString().replace(/\bcreate\b/g, "createCustom") + ")");
snippet.log("b");

snippet.log("Executing: obj.bootstrap()");
obj.bootstrap();
snippet.log("Executing: f.call(obj)");
f.call(obj);

function create(n) {
  snippet.log("create called with '" + n + "'");
}

function createCustom(n) {
  snippet.log("createCustom called with '" + n + "'");
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, I know about those two guys - but I'm not entirely what to pass as `this` should it be the Obj parent of the prototype? E.g. if I'm cloning `Test.prototype.bootstrap`, do I go for `f.call(Test, 1, 2, 3)`? I believe I tried this and nada.

Comment: @zackehh, you need pass same object like in `a.bootstrap`

Comment: @Grundy even if that's a function?

Comment: @zackehh: Pass whatever object you want `bootstrap` to be called with. Presumably the object it would normally be called directly on. (Definitely *not* `f.call(Test, ...)` in your example, `Test` is a function, `bootstrap` wouldn't normally be called with `this` referring to it.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah... so the "instance" I guess? Thanks for the awesome demo; I'll take a shot at getting this working and report back.

Comment: @zackehh: Yup, the instance.